# How to convert sql sum with case to linq

Tags: linq, sum, case

```
SUM(CASE WHEN [dbo].[tblHits].IsLike = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Likes
```

i want some thing like this  ,below code is giving me error

---

cannot implicitly convert type bool? to decimal?

`TotalLikes = grouped.Sum(d => d.IsLike == true ? d.IsLike = true : d.IsLike = false  )`

Comment: `TotalLikes = grouped.Sum(d => d.IsLike == true ? 1 : 0  )`?

Comment: `d.IsLike == true ? d.IsLike = true : d.IsLike = false` is a noop.

Comment: oh that's awesome work for me, yes i accept i'm doing a bad mistake!!

Answer (score 1):

The most direct translation would be:

```
TotalLikes = grouped.Sum(d => d.IsLike == true ? 1 : 0)
```

which can be shortened to:

```
TotalLikes = grouped.Sum(d => d.IsLike ? 1 : 0)
```

but I would use:

```
TotalLikes = grouped.Count(d=>d.IsLike);
```